# Detect embed video url from website in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm using WKWebView instead of UIWebView. But I did not get a way to fetch the url of embedded video.

I have tried with these methods:

```
[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.querySelector('video').currentSrc;" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        // result will contain the video url
 }];
```

Please suggest a method to get the embedded video url in web page using WKWebView.

Comment: in Response callback, just check the response content-type, if content-type is video/mp4 it means this is video URL, maybe content-type is diff like audio/mp4 or application/mp4 depends upon the content.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh there is response callback functions

Comment: can you find any solution for detect video url from WKWebView

Comment: @AntonyRaphel can you find any solution for that please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview